# Getting documentation from a function handle

Tags: matlab, function-pointers

Generically, if I have a function handle (but not the function name), is there a way to see the "help" comment block associated with  that function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the handle to a string with [`func2str()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/func2str.html) and call `help()` on it:

```
f = @sum;
help(func2str(f))
```

You might need to `regexp()` the string, if you have an anonymous function.